# Passing TableView Data to DetailViewController in swift

Tags: swift

I have a simple tableview loading with array of colours(each cell with different colour).i am trying to pass the background colour of detailViewController when user press the colour array cell from colourTableviewcontroller(simply i want to pass the cell colour as a detailview background colour)
my code as follows.....

```
import UIKit 

class colourTableviewcontroller: UITableViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var colorTableView: UITableView!

let colors = [UIColor.redColor(), UIColor.blueColor(),UIColor.greenColor(), UIColor.orangeColor(),UIColor.purpleColor(),UIColor.yellowColor(),UIColor.cyanColor(),UIColor.darkGrayColor(),UIColor.blackColor(), UIColor.brownColor(),UIColor.grayColor(), UIColor.magentaColor(), UIColor.whiteColor()]

var colourData = UIColor()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
   colorTableView.separatorColor = UIColor.clearColor()
}

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return colors.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("colourCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

    cell.backgroundColor = self.colors[indexPath.row % self.colors.count]

    return cell

}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    colourData = self.colors[indexPath.row]
    performSegueWithIdentifier("colourSegue", sender: self)

}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if (segue.identifier == "colourSegue") {

 let viewController = segue.destinationViewController as! DetailViewController

 viewController.bc?.backgroundColor = colourData }
}}                  

 // My DetailViewController as follows...
 import UIKit
 class DetailViewController: UIViewController {
 @IBOutlet var bc: UIView!

 override func viewDidLoad() {
 self.bc.backgroundColor = UIView.appearance().backgroundColor
 }
```

when i run the code my DetailViewController background colour changing to dark text colour when i press the colour array.....

i don't know what i am missing or am i doing wrong approach/logic....

Thanks in Advance.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- First of all in `ColourTableviewcontroller` connect the segue to the table view cell rather than to the view controller and delete the method `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`
- Replace `prepareForSegue` with

  ```
  override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
      if segue.identifier == "colourSegue" {
         let viewController = segue.destinationViewController as! DetailViewController
         let selectedIndexPath = tableView.indexPathForCell(sender as! UITableViewCell)
         viewController.color = colors[selectedIndexPath.row]
      }
  }
  ```
- In `DetailViewController` declare a variable `color`

  ```
  var color : UIColor!
  ```
- And set the color of `bc` in `viewDidLoad()`

  ```
  bc.backgroundColor = color
  ```

The reason for the additional variable is that the `IBOutlets` in `DetailViewController` don't exist yet while `prepareForSegue` is executed.

Answer (score 1):

**You aren't passing the UIColor and assigning it in the next View Controller**

You just need to do few modifications to your existing code

**1)** Add `var recievedColor : UIColor!` in the DetailViewController

**2)** In your prepareForSegue replace `viewController.bc?.backgroundColor = colourData` **with** `viewController.recievedColor = colourData`

**3)** In your DetailViewController, in viewDidLoad() function, replace `self.bc.backgroundColor = UIView.appearance().backgroundColor` **with** `self.bc.backgroundColor = recievedColor`

And there you go!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the color, then assign the color to the view on the `viewDidLoad()`. You are assigning a variable to a view that hasn't been initialized yet.

in your detail class do as follow:

```
 class DetailViewController: UIViewController {
 @IBOutlet var bc: UIView!
 var selectedBackgroundColor: UIColor? // this should be set on the prepareForSegue method.

 override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()

   if let selectedBackgroundColor = selectedBackgroundColor {
     bc.backgroundColor = selectedBackgroundColor
   }     
 }
```

Hope this helps!